# Unrecognized manifest key 'externally_connectable'

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I get this error on extension page:

```
Unrecognized manifest key 'externally_connectable'.
```

This is my manifest:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Publish",
  "externally_connectable": {
      "ids": ["*"],
      "matches": ["*://*.example.it/*"]
    },
  "description": "example ext",
  "version": "2.0",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "favicon.ico",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "background": {
    "page": "background.html"
  },

  "permissions": [
    "http://www.example.it/", "tabs", "http://localhost/", "http://www.example.it/", "https://*/*", "http://*/*", "notifications", "background"
  ],
  "web_accessible_resources": [
    "img/example.png",
    "img/bg_site.gif"
  ]
}
```

How do i solve it? I serched on BigG, no one wrote about this error...

Comment: I don't get any error when trying to load an extension with your manifest. Which version of Chrome are you running?

Comment: Version: 26.0.1410.63

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're running Chrome 26.0.1410.63, but this manifest key was added in version 29.

Sources:

- [History of the Chromium source code dealing with this manifest key](http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome/trunk/src/chrome/common/extensions/manifest_handlers/externally_connectable.h?view=log#revHEAD)
- [Bug for which this manifest key was added](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=55316)

Comment: Ok Thank you! I resolved removing Chrome, all linked folders and reinstalling it... ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If you have this error with a newer version of Chrome you might have made the same mistake I made - I had a space at the end of the key name (inside the quotes.)